# How to toggle class on onclick in map function?

Tags: reactjs, onclick

Toggling on a single element is a breeze. But I'm having a difficulty toggling with map function. Clicking a child element should toggle "active". But what's happening is that every element gets the class "active".  Take a look:

```
constructor() {
   super()
   active: false

   this.toggleClick = this.toggleClick.bind(this)
}

toggleClick() {
   this.setState(state=> ({
         active: !state.active   
      })
   )
}
```

...in my function class...

```
function ThisClass(props){
   return(
      <div>
         {
            items.map((item,i) => {
               return(
                  <span role="button" className={`${props.active ? 'active' : ''}`} key={i} onClick={() => props.toggleClick(i)}>{item.text}</span>
               )
            })
         }
      </div>
   )
}
```

This is my desired output:

```
<div>
   <span class="active">A</span>
   <span class="">B</span>
   <span class="">C</span>
</div>
```

Instead, this becomes the result

```
<div>
   <span class="active">A</span>
   <span class="active">B</span>
   <span class="active">C</span>
</div>
```

And of course, toggling should be working. a single click would make the current active. And clicking it again would remove the active state. Also, By clicking the current state, the previous active element should be stripped off with active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my own solution(along with @404notBrighton): In my state:
...instead of

```
this.state = {active:false}
```

I've changed it to

```
this.state = {active:null}
```

in my toggleClick() I've put

```
this.setState({ active: i });
if (this.state.active === i) {
   this.setState({ active: null })
}
```

then finally in my class...

```
<span role="button" className={`${props.active === i ? 'active' : ''}`} key={i} onClick={() => props.toggleClick(i)}>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to have only one active item.

You need to keep two state like selectedItemId and selectedItemState.
And update their values when button is clicked.

So you can try something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [{ id: 1, text: "A" }, { id: 2, text: "B" }, { id: 3, text: "C" }],
    selectedItemId: null,
    selectedItemState: false
  };

  toggleClick = id => {
    if (id === this.state.selectedItemId) {
      this.setState({
        selectedItemState: !this.state.selectedItemState
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        selectedItemId: id,
        selectedItemState: true
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedItemId, selectedItemState } = this.state;

    return this.state.items.map(el => (
      <div key={el.id}>
        <span
          role="button"
          className={
            el.id === selectedItemId && selectedItemState ? "active" : ""
          }
          onClick={() => this.toggleClick(el.id)}
        >
          {el.text} -{" "}
          {el.id === selectedItemId && selectedItemState ? "active" : "passive"}
        </span>
        <br />
      </div>
    ));
  }
}

export default App;
```

Sample codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-thunder-w711z

Comment: It helps but not the one I was looking for. I apologize but I have a missing statement. --- And of course, toggling should be working. a single click would make the current active. And clicking it again would remove the active state. Also, By clicking the current state, the previous active element should be stripped off with active.

Comment: @DaveMoreno  ok I updated the answer, can you check again?

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I already have a solution, much shorter than your code. Anyways, perhaps you can still help me with my escalating issue regarding class toggle. Is it okay if I tag you on the next post?

Comment: @DaveMoreno  please consider upvoting answers that helped you. Also there is no need to tag me :)

Answer (score 1):

try assigning your "active" state an index instead of a boolean

change your code

> from

className={`${props.active ? 'active' : ''}`}

> to

className={`${props.active === i ? 'active' : ''}`}

> Your toggle function must look like this

```js
toggleClick(i) {
    this.setState({ active: i })
}
```

Comment: Your answer works perfectly but not the one I was looking for. The purpose of toggle is when you click the same element again, it will negate itself of being active. Also, the other elements would negate themselves in active state after clicking the desired element.

Comment: No problem glad you found a solution